# Is there a way to alter binded UI data?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, ui

Lets say I have `searchResult.zipCode` and I want to alter the data in it before it is rendered because it returns a full zip code and not the first 5 digits of it, like how we regularly use zip-codes. I already tried the built in component from salesforce for it, but it doesn't split it up being like `10234-5678` instead leaves it as `102345678`. Would I need to to alter it on the JavaScript side before it binds just to insert the "-" between chars 4 and 5? Any documentation or examples on how I would alter binding data before it renders?

HTML:

```
<template for:each = {searchResults} for:item="searchResult">
    <lightning-layout key={searchResult.ID}>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <div class="custom-box">
                <lightning-formatted-address
                    street={searchResults.address}
                    city={searchResults.city}
                    province={searchResults.state}
                    postal-code={searchResults.zipCode}>
                </lightning-formatted-address>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
...
```

JS:

```
    @api searchResults;

    showPhoneSearchResults() {
        let params = '{"phone":'+this.inputPhoneNumber+'}';
        retrievePhoneSearch({paramter:params})
        .then(data => {
            this.searchResults = data;})
        .catch(error =>
            //error handling
        });
    }
```

`retrievePhoneSearch()` is just an apex function that takes a parameter and hits an external api to retrieve results. Didn't include code of it, since I didn't think it is relevant.

Comment: Are you able to include your existing component code/attempt with an [edit]?

Comment: yeah, give me a moment. I will add part of the UI and some of the JS if that helps

Comment: @KrisGoncalves added code

Comment: Have you looked at what your `data` looks like in your js to confirm it actually has the format you desire `10234-5678`?

Comment: yes, I have looked at my JS to confirm that is the desired format I want given the results. For a real world example `60618-0012`, my json response is `606180012` so I am trying to transform the JSON on the UI to change zipCodes to have the '-' between chars 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, as you guessed, have to change the value yourself. `lightning-formatted-address` just displays it as you pass it.

You can choose to do that within the apex method or within the LWC.

To change it within the LWC, you'd have to clone the `data` if your apex method is cached as cached items are read-only. From there, it's just doing whatever logic you want (dash after 5 numbers) and you can utilize the [slice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```
 showPhoneSearchResults() {
        let params = '{"phone":'+this.inputPhoneNumber+'}';
        retrievePhoneSearch({paramter:params})
        .then(data => {
            let returnedResults = {...data}; //clone value over if your apex method is cached
            returnedResults.zipCode = returnedResults.zipCode.slice(0,5) + '-' + returnedResults.zipCode.slice(5);
            this.searchResults = returnedResults;
        })
        .catch(error =>
            //error handling
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for commenting. Wanted to make sure I didn't end up over thinking it and was doing more work than I had to. I'll go ahead and try this out, but seems like the only way to do it.